# Lebesgue measurability of $f\circ g$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be Lebesgue measurable and $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be continuous. Do we also need extra conditions to ensure that $f\circ g$ is Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: What are you trying to show?

Comment: Did you mean for $f$ to be continuous and $g$ to be Lebesgue measurable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you meant $f$ continuous and $g$ Lebesgue measurable. Note that for any open set $U$ we have $$(f \circ g)^{-1}(U) =g^{-1}(f^{-1}(U)). $$
Since $f$ is continuous $f^{-1}(U)$ is open. Then since $g$ is Lebesgue measurable and $f^{-1}(U)$ is open, $g^{-1}(f^{-1}(U))$ is Lebesgue measurable. It follows that $f \circ g$ is Lebesgue measurable.

Easy to show and more useful: Allow $f$ to be any Borel function, not just a continuous function. Consider $\mathscr{A} := \{A \subseteq \mathbb{R} : g^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{L} \}$ and show $\mathscr{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing open sets. Thus $g^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{L}$ for all $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Repeat the argument for continuous functions with this new piece of information.

If you did mean $f$ Lebesuge measurable and $g$ continuous, then you need the additional assumption that $f$ is Borel measurable.